# Python my_socket.connect() OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, sockets, errno, oserror

When I try:

```
import socket
import os


my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

devices = []
print("Looking for open server. . .")
for device in os.popen('arp -a'):
    devices.append(device.split()[1].strip("()"))  # .strip("()")
# print(devices)

make_server = True
host = "192.168.4.24"  # "127.0.1.1"
port = 8000
for device in devices:
    try:
        my_socket.connect((device, port))
        make_server = False
        print(f"Connected to {device}")
        break
    except socket.error as error:
        pass
        # print(error)

if make_server:
    my_socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port))
    print(f"Connected to {socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())}")
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/LAN_chat_app/Testing 1.py", line 41, in <module>
    my_socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

after some testing it seems that in:

```
for device in devices:
    try:
        my_socket.connect((device, port))
        make_server = False
        print(f"Connected to {device}")
        break
    except socket.error as error:
        pass
```

after the first iteration it has the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/LAN_chat_app/Testing 1.py", line 29, in <module>
    my_socket.connect((device, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

which it handles, the second iteration instead returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/LAN_chat_app/Testing 1.py", line 29, in <module>
    my_socket.connect((device, port))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

it seems to only try to connect to the first ip in the list and the rest it just returns this error, in other words, `my_socket.connect((device, port))` only runs once.

#SYSTEM

IDE:
PyCharm 2021.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-211.6693.115, built on April 6, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.35 x86_64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.intellij.laf.enable.animation=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: IdeaVIM (1.9.2), Key Promoter X (2021.1.1), cn.haojiyou.CodeGlance3 (2.0.1), com.intellij.ideolog (203.0.30.0), com.mallowigi (36.0), com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.6.0), com.nasller.CodeGlancePro (1.3.8-Last2021.3.x), com.tabnine.TabNine (0.7.21), io.acari.DDLCTheme (78.2-1.1.1), io.unthrottled.amii (0.15.1), zd.zero.waifu-motivator-plugin (2.2.0), intellij-micropython (1.3.1), izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (6.25), org.exbin.deltahex.intellij (0.2.6)

Comment: Well, that error probably turns up hundreds of times in a search. Further, does this happen without multithreading? Please make sure you actually have a [mcve] included in your question, along with the full backtrace, so people don't have to search for the line the error occurs. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've done as you suggested. also the code that I think is causing the issue is line 27-34, the for device in devices loop.

Comment: The line throwing the exception is only called if previous code caused an error, which you actively silenced and ignored.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, I wanted it to go through a list of ip's and try to connect to them, but it only tries to connect to the first one, how do I do that without running connect() multiple times, do I have to ping it or something?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, nor how the code actually behaves from your description. Please step through the code in a debugger. Doing so, it will quickly become apparent where it takes the wrong turn and probably also why. Try to find a video tutorial for whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: I did and I edited the question.